# Ambiguous use of `setImageWith(_:placeholderImage:usingActivityIndicatorStyle:)` in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, sdwebimage

This Code working fine in Swift 2.3, but while i am upgrading to Swift 3.0, compiler complains about ambiguous use.

```
imgProfilePhoto?.setImageWith((URL(string: profileurl)), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "PatientDefaultProfilePic"), usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)
```

Comment: Try to rewrite the method Xcode will suggest you for the correct way to implement in Swift 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift equivalent method works as replacement of this method from `SDWebImage` :

```
imgProfilePhoto?.sd_setImageWithIndicator(with: URL(string: profileurl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "PatientDefaultProfilePic"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4

```
import SDWebImage
extension UIImageView {

@objc func setImageWithIndicator(urlStr: String?, placeholder: UIImage) {
    guard let _ = urlStr, let url = URL(string: urlStr!) else {
        image = placeholder
        return
    }
    sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
    sd_addActivityIndicator()
    sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: placeholder, options: .refreshCached, completed: nil)
}}
```

Swift 3

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: ""))
imageView.setShowActivityIndicator(true)
imageView.setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line also worked for me:

Add completion handler nil.

```
imgView.setImageWith(imgUrl, completed: nil, usingActivityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
```